# The method 'updateData' isn't defined for the type 'Query'. Futter, Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to update data in a document based on a query. Here is my code:

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection("Categories")
    .where("userEmail", isEqualTo: "${user?.email}")
    .updateData({"category_budget_remaining": _remainingCategoryBudget2})
    .then((value){});
```

I am getting the following error: The method 'updateData' isn't defined for the type 'Query'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after `where()` you need to get documents then do updating

```
where(...).getDocuments().then((val)=> 
   val.documents.forEach((doc)=> {
     doc.reference.updateData({...})
   });
});
```

this code selects and updates all documents that goes true for where condition. If you want do it just for 1 document then just add `.limitTo(1)` before `getDocuments()`.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the API documentation, [where()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html) returns a Query, and Query doesn't have a method called `updateData()`.  So, what you're seeing here is no surprise.

Firestore doesn't offer a way to bulk update documents like a SQL "update where" command.  What you will have to do is execute the query for the documents to change, iterate the documents in the result set, and update each one individually.  Yes, it requires a document read for every document to change, and no, there are no alternatives for this.

Answer (score 1):

For me worked by changing

```
.updateData
```

to just

```
.update
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to @Habib Mahamadi but this is the correct and only way to acheive this functionality, my answer is little differente as firebase has changed names of functions.

```
Firestore.instance
        .collection("Categories")
        .where("userEmail", isEqualTo: "${user?.email}")
        .then((value)=> value.docs.forEach((element){element.reference.update({"" : ""})});
```